# GROUP BY and Aggregation over a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT IsConfirmed, IsNetConfirmed, d.FullDate FROM Final.FactApplication f 
INNER JOIN final.DimOfferedDate d on f.OfferedDateKey= d.OfferedDateKey
WHERE d.CalendarYear in ('2013','2014','2015')
```

The code above returns the following sample data.

```
IsConfirmed IsNetConfirmed  FullDate
----------------------------------------------  
1           0               2013-01-04 00:00:00.000   
1           1               2013-02-04 00:00:00.000
0           1               2013-03-04 00:00:00.000
1           0               2013-04-04 00:00:00.000
```

I wish to aggregate the sum of both IsConfirmed and IsNetConfirmed over day and month for each year so that I end up with the following result. I need to aggregate for each year so that the sum for 4/31/2012 includes the data between 1/1/2012-4/31/2012.
[image]

Here is my code so far - but I can't wrap my head around all the groupings. Help, please.

```
SELECT sum(IsConfirmed) AS ConfirmCount
    ,sum(IsNetConfirmed) AS NetConfirmCount
    ,year(d.fulldate) AS cyear
    ,month(d.fulldate) AS cmonth
    ,day(d.fulldate) AS cday
FROM final.FactApplicationHistory f
INNER JOIN final.DimOfferedDate d ON f.OfferedDateKey = d.OfferedDateKey
WHERE d.CalendarYear IN ('2013','2014','2015')
GROUP BY year(d.fulldate)
    ,month(d.fulldate)
    ,day(d.fulldate)
ORDER BY year(d.fulldate)
```

Comment: You're going to have to either work out a pivot approach, or use case statements for all your sums. Something like `sum(case when year(fulldate)  = 2012 then IsConfirmed else 0 end) as 2012Confirmed`.

Comment: @andrew, I need to aggregate for each year so that for example, the sum for 4/31/2012 includes the data between 1/1/2012-4/31/2012. How would I do that?

Comment: So are you looking for some sort of running total then? So, for your first row, `2012 Confirm` would have 2012-01-01 through 2012-04-15, `2013 Confirm` would have 2013-01-01 through 2013-04-15, etc?

Comment: That's the phrase I was looking for. So, DayMonth of 4/15 for 2012Confirm and 2013 confirm should have 2012-01-01 through 2012-04-15 and 2013-01-01 through 2013-04-15 respectively. Similarly, DayMonth of 7/15 for 2012Confirm and 2013 confirm should have 2012-01-01 through 2012-07-15 and 2013-01-01 through 2013-07-15 respectively. I hope this helps.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @wewesthemenace I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running sums are tricky.  You can't really do them with just a group by.  There are a couple of ways to do it.  One way is to join the data table with itself on all records that are less than or equal in value to the current record and sum the data points.  You're query is especially complicated by the fact that you also want to pivot the data.  Here's how you would do it with the table join method:

```
;with temp (IsConfirmed, IsNetConfirmed, FullDate) AS
(
SELECT IsConfirmed, IsNetConfirmed, FullDate
FROM final.FactApplicationHistory f
INNER JOIN final.DimOfferedDate d 
ON f.OfferedDateKey = d.OfferedDateKey
WHERE d.CalendarYear IN ('2013','2014','2015')
)
, pivottable (cmonthday,cmonth,cday,ConfirmCount2013,NetConfirmCount2013,ConfirmCount2014,NetConfirmCount2014,ConfirmCount2015,NetConfirmCount2015) AS
(
    SELECT
        dateadd(day,cday,(DATEADD(month, cmonth, 0))) cmonthday,
        cmonth,
        cday,
        sum(isnull([2013],0)) ConfirmCount2013, 
        sum(isnull([2016],0)) NetConfirmCount2013, 
        sum(isnull([2014],0)) ConfirmCount2014, 
        sum(isnull([2017],0)) NetConfirmCount2014, 
        sum(isnull([2015],0)) ConfirmCount2015, 
        sum(isnull([2018],0)) NetConfirmCount2015
    FROM 
        (SELECT sum(IsConfirmed) AS ConfirmCount
            ,sum(IsNetConfirmed) AS NetConfirmCount
            ,year(d.FullDate) AS cyear
            ,year(d.FullDate)+3 AS cyear2
            ,month(d.FullDate) AS cmonth
            ,day(d.FullDate) AS cday
        FROM #temp d
        WHERE year(FullDate) IN ('2013','2014','2015')
        GROUP BY year(d.FullDate)
            ,month(d.FullDate)
            ,day(d.FullDate)
        ) ps
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM (ConfirmCount)
    FOR cyear IN
    ( [2013],[2014],[2015])
    ) AS pvt
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM (NetConfirmCount)
    FOR cyear2 IN
    ( [2016],[2017],[2018])
    ) AS pvt
    Group by cmonth,
        cday
)
select
    pivottable.cmonth,
    pivottable.cday,
    sum(RunningSums.ConfirmCount2013) ConfirmCount2013, 
    sum(RunningSums.NetConfirmCount2013) NetConfirmCount2013, 
    sum(RunningSums.ConfirmCount2014) ConfirmCount2014, 
    sum(RunningSums.NetConfirmCount2014) NetConfirmCount2014, 
    sum(RunningSums.ConfirmCount2015) ConfirmCount2015, 
    sum(RunningSums.NetConfirmCount2015) NetConfirmCount2015
from pivottable
join pivottable RunningSums
on RunningSums.cmonthday <= pivottable.cmonthday
group by pivottable.cmonth,pivottable.cday
order by pivottable.cmonth, pivottable.cday
```

I suppose this might even be a case where a cursor would actually be a good idea.  You could create your output pivot data into a table and then iterate though each record and update each value with the running sum.  For a very large table with millions of records this would probably be more efficient than my self join method.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution definitely works. However, here is what I have recently discovered. Both the IsConfirmed and IsNetConfirmed values might change down the road. So, IsNetConfirmed might be 1 on 4/15 (which will return the sum(IsNetConfirmed) = 1) but it might be set to 0 on 4/16 which will give a sum of 0 :-( This tends to happen during the later part of the year. So, is our running total approach moot here? I am not sure how to approach this issue. I have attached a screenshot of some old data in Excel that shows this behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Are you saying that previous reports are showing the numbers decreasing?  If so... this could only happen if there are negative values in your data.

Comment: Brian, your solution works for the running total requirement. So, I am going to accept your answer :-) The issue I brought up might require me to look at the transaction level data and figure out how to replicate the sample report that I had attached. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to generate all possible month-date and year combination. For example, in 2013 you have dates from Jan 1 - Jan 5 and in 2014, you have dates from Jan 3 - Jan 6. You should have dates Jan 1 - Jan 6 for both year 2013 and 2014. After getting all the dates, `JOIN` it with your original query so that each newly generated date has value for `IsConfirmed` and `IsNetConfirmed`. From that, you get the running total. Finally, you would want to `PIVOT` the running total to achieve the desired result.

Here is a dynamic approach using Crosstab. You can read this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/) for reference.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a56c8/2/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = '',
        @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = '',
        @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 =
';WITH SampleData AS( -- Replace this CTE with the original query
    SELECT * FROM Data
)
,CrossDates AS( -- Generate date combinations
    SELECT
        YY, MM, DD,
        FullDate = DATEADD(DAY, DD - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, MM - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, YY - 1900, 0)))        
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            MM = MONTH(FullDate),
            DD = DAY(FullDate)
        FROM SampleData
    )DM
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT YY = YEAR(FullDate) FROM SampleData
    )Y
)
,CteAllDates AS( -- Assign value for each newly generated date
    SELECT
        c.*,
        IsConfirmed = ISNULL(s.IsConfirmed, 0),
        IsNetConfirmed = ISNULL(s.IsNetConfirmed, 0)
    FROM CrossDates c
    LEFT JOIN SampleData s
        ON s.FullDate = c.FullDate
)
,RunningTotal AS( -- Compute running total
    SELECT
        YY = YEAR(FullDate),
        MM = MONTH(FullDate),
        DD = DAY(FullDate),
        Confirm = SUM(CAST(IsConfirmed AS INT)) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(FullDate) ORDER BY MONTH(FullDate), DAY(FullDate)),
        NetConfirm = SUM(CAST(IsNetConfirmed AS INT)) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(FullDate) ORDER BY MONTH(FullDate), DAY(FullDate))
    FROM CteAllDates
)
SELECT
      MM
    , DD
'

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN YY = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YY) + ' THEN Confirm ELSE 0 END) AS [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YY) + ' Confirm]' + CHAR(10) +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN YY = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YY) + ' THEN NetConfirm ELSE 0 END) AS [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YY) + ' NetConfirm]' + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT YY = YEAR(FullDate)
    FROM(
        SELECT * FROM Data -- Replace this with the original query
    )d
)t

SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM RunningTotal
GROUP BY MM, DD'

PRINT(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

---

*Notes:*

*1. Replace the `SampleData` with your original query.*

*2. `SUM() OVER()` is used to get the running total.*

*3. Basically, replace `SELECT * FROM Data` with your oqriginal query.*

---

**Sample Data**

```
IsConfirmed IsNetConfirmed FullDate
----------- -------------- -----------------------
1           0              2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
1           1              2013-04-02 00:00:00.000
0           1              2013-04-03 00:00:00.000
1           0              2013-04-04 00:00:00.000
1           0              2014-04-01 00:00:00.000
1           1              2014-04-02 00:00:00.000
0           1              2014-04-03 00:00:00.000
1           0              2014-04-05 00:00:00.000
```

**Result**

```
|----|----|--------------|-----------------|--------------|-----------------|
| MM | DD | 2013 Confirm | 2013 NetConfirm | 2014 Confirm | 2014 NetConfirm |
|----|----|--------------|-----------------|--------------|-----------------|
|  4 |  1 |            1 |               0 |            1 |               0 |
|  4 |  2 |            2 |               1 |            2 |               1 |
|  4 |  3 |            2 |               2 |            2 |               2 |
|  4 |  4 |            3 |               2 |            2 |               2 |
|  4 |  5 |            3 |               2 |            3 |               2 |
```

Comment: Thanks @wewesthemenace for the solution. However, as I have outlined in my response to Brian below, I might need to come up with another approach on attacking this problem.